# pythonanywhere [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'My Project-XXXXXXXXX.json'

Tags: python, django-views, pythonanywhere

> I deploied a web app on pythonanywhere but I got this error from
>   view.py.I tried to change SECRETS_FILE = "absolute path" but it still
>   couldn't find .json.Does anyone who had met this error before and
>   solved it?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pandas as pd
import json
import sys
import os
#import c3pyo as c3

# Create your views here.
def welcome(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def questionnaire(request):
    print("Current folder: " + os.getcwd())
    SCOPE = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds"]
    SECRETS_FILE ="My Project-XXXXXXXXX.json"
    SPREADSHEET = "BackHarbor"

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPE)
    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    workbook = gc.open(SPREADSHEET)
    # Get the first sheet
    sheet = workbook.sheet1
    data = pd.DataFrame(sheet.get_all_records())
```

> error message

```
FileNotFoundError at /result
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'My Project-XXXXXXXXX.json'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://yujing.pythonanywhere.com/result
Django Version: 1.8.18
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'My Project-XXXXXXXX.json'
Exception Location: /home/YuJing/django_project_venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/oauth2client/service_account.py in from_json_keyfile_name, line 219
```

Comment: It's probably related to the location of the file; I see you're printing out the result of `os.getcwd` just above this code -- is the working directory that it prints out definitely the one that includes the secrets file?

Answer (score 0):

cant access your file My Project-XXXXXXXXX.json

Try to rename this file from 'My Project-XXXXXXXXX.json' to 'MyPoject-XXXXXXXXX.json'

or this may work i dont know

you can add a backslash before the space

`SECRETS_FILE ="My\ Project-XXXXXXXXX.json"`